# Want to make AJAX pause, show a progress bar for 2s then continue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I wrote an application to ask users questions in a survey-type application.
When the user clicks on an answer, AJAX (w/jQuery) calls PHP to record the answer, then shows the next question. That all works fine.
The problem is, I would like to show some statistics to the user for two seconds after clicking an answer. To do this I call a function to SHOW the stats div, then wait two seconds, HIDE that div then SHOW the new question.

The problem is, the screen 'freezes' when I use the .wnen, .then jQuery functions, so I cannot use an animated gif to let the user know the next question is coming. The GIF just freezes along with the rest of the screen.

Here is the function I'm using to show the next question.

Is there any better way to pause that what I am doing?

the URL is: www.imazy.com/askQuestions.php

The function below is called like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "recordUserAns.php",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    async: false,

    success: function(html){

        showNextQn(html);

    }
});
```

---

```
function showNextQn($response){
    // -------------- Pause and fade in/out -------------- //

    var btnVal = document.getElementById("toggleStats").innerHTML;

    if( btnVal == "Show Stats" ){ // Change the text
        var showStats = 0;
    }else{
        var showStats = 1;
    }

    function showDiv(){

        var dfd = $.Deferred();

        if ( showStats ){
            $('.ansPercent').fadeIn(fadeInTime, dfd.resolve);  // Show the hidden div
            // $('span#progBar').fadeIn(fadeInTime, dfd.resolve); // Show the progress bar
        }else{
            $('#content').fadeOut(fadeOutTime, dfd.resolve);
        }
        return dfd.promise();
    }

    $.when( showDiv() )
        .then(function( ajaxResult ){

            if ( showStats ){   
                pauseScript(qnPauseTime); // Pause given # milliseconds
            }
            // $('span#progBar').fadeOut(0); // Hide the progress bar
            $('#content').html($response); // Return the NEXT question
            $('#content').fadeIn(fadeInTime);

            // 'ajaxResult' is the server's response
        });

    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.visibility="Visible";

    // Remove every instance of the class, as it is no longer needed
    $('a.ansHolder').removeClass('selected');
}
```

Comment: `async: false` will lock up the browser, so be careful when using it.

Answer (score 1):

Send the Ajax request and make sure it is sent asynchronous. Then, show the progress bar and start a timer (setTimeout) to start the two seconds. After the timer is finished, you set one flag and call a 'NextQuestion' procedure. When the ajax request finishes, you set another flag, and call NextQuestion again. In NextQuestion you check if both flags are set. If that is the case, you will show the next question. That way, you are sure you wait at least two seconds, and will not continue before the request returns, but still you don't wait longer than necessary.